# LoadRunner - using a %d in lr_eval_string function

Tags: c, performance, testing, loadrunner

I need to create a string with multiple values of `'x'`.

For instance I tried saving a string while referencing another variable as such:

```
lr_save_string("xyz", lr_eval_string("{x_%d}", intVar));
```

I've also have tried:

```
lr_save_string(lr_eval_string("{x_%d}", intVar), "xyz");
```

Is there any option/way to use %d and a int variable which always changes in the `lr_eval_string` function? or, how could this be performed?

Comment: see C function sprintf()

Answer (score 0):

You have to **use sprintf** function like below,

```
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(20); // allocate size as per your requirement
sprintf(buffer,"{x_%d}", intvar);
lr_save_string(lr_eval_string(buffer),"xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of `Loadrunner` you may use the array functions:

```
lr_save_string(lr_paramarr_idx("x", intvar), "xyz");
```